# using property file along with config file to be used with mxmlc

Tags: mxmlc

I'm trying to run mxmlc in the following manner.

```
mxmlc -load-config+=mycfg.xml C:\\projects\\src\\main.mxml -output myswf.swf
```

In the config file, I want to keep some values configurable, for example the paths of the external libraries. Is it possible to include a property file into the config file and use it as {property_name} in the config file?

Or is it possible to pass certain arguments from the command line itself that will override/replace the corresponding values in the config file, like the -D option in the ant command?

Please provide your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

From the [LiveDocs for mxmlc / -load-config](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_13.html):

> If you specify a configuration file,
>   you can override individual options by
>   setting them on the command line.